# Divisor class group of an affine surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89352/what-is-the-picard-group-of-z3-yy2-x2x-1#comment680717_89352) the OP considers the following surface: $X=\mathcal{Z}(z^3-y(y^2-x^2)(x-1))$. (The field it's not explicitely mentioned, but for geometric reasons this can be algebraically closed.) He claims that the divisor class group of this surface is $$\mathrm{Cl}(X)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^{3}\oplus \mathbb{Z}^{2}.$$

I'd like to know how to prove this and the geometric arguments behind.

Comment: Obviously the coordinate ring of this variety is an integral domain. Is it also normal?

Comment: Yes it is normal. The jacobian criterion shows that $X$ has only 4 singular points: $(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (1, 1, 0)$ and $(1,-1,0)$. As $X$ is a complete intersection, hence Cohen-Macaulay, one can apply Serre's criterion of normality. This can also be checked directly viewing $O(X)$ as a finite extension of $K[x,y]$ defined by $z^3=f(x,y)$ with $f$ without multiple factor.

Comment: I can see some $3$-torsion elements in Cl$(X)$: each  curve $C$ among $x=1$; $x=y$; $x=-y$; $y=0$ defines a $3$-torsion points because $3C$ is respectively the principal divisor div$(x-1)$; div$(x-y)$ etc. The principal divisor div$(z)$ is the sum the 4 curves, so we get three copies of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ (I don't say they are independent, but this should not be hard). But this is just a piece of the whole divisor class group.

Comment: This question is unfortunately too old to be migrated.  The only course of action is to ask it over at MO (including whatever of the comments you feel are useful), and deleting this copy of it.